# Insert None while iterating list of months

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with a range of year/month. Then, I also have a count of users with this format: total_users, month, year.

Basically I need to insert `None` when there is no count value for the month in all_months_necessary.

```
all_months_necessary=('2015/1', '2015/2', '2015/3', '2015/4', '2015/5', '2015/6', '2015/7', '2015/8', '2015/9', '2015/10', '2015/11', '2015/12', '2016/1')

users_count=[(2L, 1.0, 2015.0), (1L, 3.0, 2015.0), (1L, 1.0, 2016.0)]
```

I am trying this code, but the problem is that I will have more Nones than expected.

```
data=()
for each_month in all_months_necessary:                        
    for total, month, year in users_count:
        if each_month == str(int(year))+'/'+str(int(month)):
            data = data + (total,)
        else:
            data = data + (None,)
```

expected:     `data=(2L, None, 1L, None, None, ..., 1L)`

Comment: Why are you using a tuple for a homogeneous sequence?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what homogeneous sequence are you talking about? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to convert `users_count` to dictionary.
Yet another <strike>one</strike>twoliner:

```
user_count_dict = {str(int(year))+'/'+str(int(month)): total for total, month, year in users_count}
# get(x) returns None if a key not in the dict
data = [user_count_dict.get(x) for x in all_months_necessary]
```

And plus to Jason for explanations

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new list element each time you cycle through the second for loop, which means that for each `each_month` you have three entries in `data`, not one entry as you expect. Here's a fix:

```
data=()
i = 0
for each_month in all_months_necessary:                        
    for total, month, year in users_count:
        if each_month == str(int(year))+'/'+str(int(month)):
            data = data + (total,)
            break
    else:
        data = data + (None,)
```

Comment: I would `break` once the match found and drop `i` altogether

Comment: Thanks @robyschek. I added a break and fixed a small bug. How would you eliminate `i`? The difficulty is in fact that `for total, month, year in users_count` is actually marching through three separate list elements, so I need a way to keep track of how many non-matches have occurred. Would love any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that `for` statement may be followed by [`else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) block which is exectuted when no break occured. Append `None` there

Comment: @robyschek thanks a lot for that suggestion. I made the change and it worked, so code above is edited. Your two-line dict solution is a great one. Thanks again.

Comment: Jason, yeah, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, but works for what I need.

```
user_count_data=[]
for total, month, year in users_count:
    d={}
    d['month_year'] = str(int(year))+'/'+str(int(month))
    d['count'] = total
    user_count_data.append(d)

data=()
for each_month in all_months_necessary:              
    data = data + (next((item['count'] for item in user_count_data if item.get("month_year") and item["month_year"] == each_month), None), )
```

output: `(2L, None, 1L, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1L)`